# How to access the latest version of the Darwin Kernel Programming Guide?

Tags: kernel, documentation

The [Darwin Kernel Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KernelProgramming/About/About.html) has been last updated on 2013-08-08, and the mention "Documentation archive" is in the title bar.

So, my question is : How to access the latest version of the Darwin Kernel Programming Guide?

Comment: It's called XNU now, so you might want to start there....https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/xnu

Comment: @Allan No, it's not called XNU now - there hasn't been any renaming. XNU is the operating system kernel. Darwin is the complete operating system (so XNU is a part of Darwin).

Comment: @jksoegaard - The Darwin *kernel* was called [Mach](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KernelProgramming/Mach/Mach.html). It's now XNU.  So, yes, the *kernel* is now called XNU.  And since the OP is looking for *kernel development* they should be pointed into the appropriate direction.

Comment: @Allan That is simply not correct. The kernel Apple has produced for Darwin has always been named XNU. XNU contains modified parts of the Mach kernel, that's not at all the same. What you're saying is similar to saying that Hurd was once named Mach. It's not the case.

Comment: @jksoegaard, so, you're saying that the kernel in Darwin is XNU?  I just want to make sure I get my facts straight.

Comment: You might want to check out Wikipedia's article about Darwin, there's a fair amount of information about its history. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_(operating_system)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular document does not have a newer version released. The information contained therein now lives on in a number of different places in newer versions.

For third party kernel programming documentation, such as for creating kernel extensions and drivers, you want to look at this URL:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/kernel/